# How to return only error messages in custom response model in c#

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0

I set up the fluent validator in my web api project and validations are working fine. But I want to create one common response structure for every API. When fluent validation getting failed I get response in BadRequest response structure like given below.

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-f3b3363d741fe7416fe40aea0ff13c36-d08e5eefbc2ff0ea-00",
  "errors": {
    "Code": [
      "'Code' must not be empty."
    ],
    "Name": [
      "'Name' must not be empty."
    ]
  }
}
```

And my domain code is like below

```
public class AddRegionRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<AddRegionRequest>
{
    public AddRegionRequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(r=>r.Code).NotEmpty().NotNull().WithMessage("{property} is required");
        RuleFor(r=>r.Name).NotEmpty().NotNull().WithMessage("{property} is required");
    }
}
```

now I want to create one common response structure for every API where I can return isSuccessful flag, data(if present),errorList and message.

```
public class Response{
    public bool IsSuccessful{get;set;}
    public dynamic Data{get;set;}
    public List<string> ErrorList{get;set;}
    public string Message{get;set;}
}
```

but I need help to know how I can get only errors from fluent validation Bad Request structure and create custom response like "Response" class.

I want response like below.

```
{
    isSuccessful:false,
    data:null,
    errorList:[
    "'Code' must not be empty.",
    "'Name' must not be empty."
    ],
    message:null
}
```

I tried to readonly error message and add it in collection, but I failed and don't know how to create common response structure and pass fluent validation error messages string thorough list in common response structure.

Comment: You already have what you want. That structure is a standard ProblemDetails response defined in RFC7231. This allows *every* client to read and handle validation problems without requiring custom coding to match the API. This is generated by ASP.NET Core's validation middleware, *not* Fluent Validation. You can return your own `ProblemDetails` response in your controller actions with eg `return Problem(..)`. Any client based on OpenAPI should be able to handle a ProblemDetails response

Comment: Check the sections in [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors) on validation problems and customization. If a request is bad, ASP.NET Core will return a 400 response and never call the action. You can customize that response if needed, or you can return your own based on some extra validation